# How to make the HP 6700 print with empty colour cartridges driver?

Tags: printer

Is there a way to make the HP 6700 printer print with empty colour cartridges.
It fails if the colour cartridges are empty.
It is upsetting that they would mislead the consumer, is there a non-proprietary driver to help the situation?

Comment: Have you tried removing the empty cartridges

Comment: For technical reasons, the printhead *must* have ink in it at all times. See http://superuser.com/questions/409473/how-to-print-in-black-and-white-when-a-color-ink-cartridge-is-out-of-ink/1052770#1052770

Answer (score 0):

Like most inkjets (and lasers), the 6700 will not print when one of the cartridges is empty. Even when printing greyscale, colour inks may still be used to achieve a greater range of greys.

For HP's official explanation, see [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03773211&tmp_task=useCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5058338).

Comment: Well their explanation is hog wash, you do not need colour for grey

Comment: Whether it's hogwash or not (and it isn't), if they design the printer so it will only work if all cartridges have ink, there's not much you can do about it!

Comment: Actually it is `hogwash`, do you work for hp or something. Grey does not contain any `foo` `king` colours(non blacka and white). There is something we can do and that is re-engineer the sytem software of the printer...

Comment: @Stevie Have fun rewriting the printer firmware ;-)

Comment: From the HP OfficeJet 6700 User guide Chapter 7, page 74: "The printer can still operate when the black ink cartridge or one or more color ink cartridges are depleted, but it will print more slowly. Also, the quality of printed documents might be affected." and "If a color cartridge is depleted, the printer will print in grayscale using the black
cartridge."